# what's it called when you have a data structure that looks like an org chart?

Tags: computer-science

This is me showing that I didn't get a CS degree. What I'm wondering is what the heck you call this:

- every node has a id (unique) and a parentId
- the node at the top of the tree has no parentId
- a parent node can have 0...n child nodes, or maybe it's more correct to say that a parent node id can appear in 0..n nodes

Seems simple right? But it's not a b-tree as far as I can tell, since it's not balanced. Is it an unbalanced tree? Couldn't find an entry in wikipedia for that so I assume that the term doesn't exist.

Edit: I was really stuck on this thing *not* being a b-tree, so I thought there would be a term for trees that are not balanced. And there is: tree.

Comment: Is it really subjective?

Comment: Whether it's subjective or not is subjective :P

Comment: The gaps in your definition are: are the links uni- or bi-directional? oOw many parent nodes can a child node have?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At the most general it is a graph. Since there is a directed relationship between the nodes (namely from the child nodes to the parent) it is also a directed graph or digraph. Presumably there are no loops in the graph (i.e. A -> B, B -> C, C -> A) so it is an **directed acyclical graph** (DAG). And since there is also likely to be a single root node it is also a tree.

Comment: see that's the computer science type answer I was going for, thanks

Answer (score 14):

Isn't it a simple [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure))?

Comment: Yup. some would probably call it a n-ary ordered tree.

Comment: Don't think it's an ordered tree. As stated, there is no need to sort siblings. There is no natural order that applies.

Call it an n-ary unordered tree.

Answer (score 3):

I would simply call it a tree. Though technically there may be a term for a non-binary && non-balanced tree.  IMO, tree works fine.  I might also refer to it as hierarchical data.

Answer (score 3):

A really screwed up organization may only be able to represented by a graph. ;-)

Comment: Matrix management, or even just a few "dotted lines" would mean it wasn't a tree without being totally screwed.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a tree. There's no need for any more distinction than that, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

As long as any one node does not reference more than one direct parent, then it can be a tree.

Answer (score 1):

A mathematician would say it is a *rooted tree*, as in graph theory [trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)) need not have a root.

In computer science almost all trees come with roots, so as the others have pointed out it is called just a tree.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone points out, you probably don't need anything more complicated than a tree.

To the more complicated structures like a graph, it's not entirely crazy.

See [Martin Fowler's paper](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/accountability.pdf) on accountability structures. That said, I can say from first hand experience, it's better to avoid modeling an org tree as a graph, when you don't need it.